# Post a Joda LocalDateTime as a property. Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have to controller that takes a controller that a Notification and returns a json response.

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseWrapper<Notification> addNotification(
                                                         @RequestParam(required = false) String password,
                                                         @Valid Notification notification,
                                                         BindingResult bindingResult ){.....}
```

My Notification that is posted includes a LocalDateTime.

```
notification.time
```

How can map a String to LocalDateTime when posting. CustomPropertyEditor or is there a better approach.

Also the time is in my wrapper. How can I format it? LocalDateTime in json includes a lot of information I don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate your field with [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) and provide a pattern. For example

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDateTime time;
```

If Spring finds jodatime on your class path, it will use an appropriate `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the `String` date value from the request and generate a `LocalDateTime` object.

Comment: Thank I would be to post the ISO standard. I saw there was an ISO option in the annotation but not sure if it is what I need. I would also like to support multiple formats if possible. But you solution worked in the way that I got a String converted to a date.